# Dictionary formation in python

Tags: python

I am trying to read a passage and make a dictionary out of the passage. The keys are the words and the values are the line numbers. The following is my code:

```
import string
def build_word_index():
    input_file=(input('file name: '))
    input_file_open=open(input_file,'r')

    word_map = {}
    line_no = 0
    w=[]

    for line in input_file_open:

        word_lst = line.strip().split()

        word_lst = [w.lower().strip(string.punctuation) for w in word_lst]

        w.append(word_lst)           

        for word in w[line_no]:
            if word!="":
                word_map[word]=line_no
        line_no+=1

    print(word_map)

    index_lst = sorted(list(word_map.items()))
    print(index_lst)

    for word, line_set in index_lst:
        line_lst = sorted(list(line_set))
        line_str = str( line_lst[0] )
        for line_no in line_lst[1:]:
            line_str += ", {}".format( line_no )
        print("{:14s}:".format(word), line_str )



    input_file_open.close()

build_word_index()
```

The error that I am getting is:
ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dasinator/Documents/Books IX/Python Examples/textbook examples/lab10/lab10d.py", line 39, in <module>
    build_word_index()
  File "C:/Users/Dasinator/Documents/Books IX/Python Examples/textbook examples/lab10/lab10d.py", line 29, in build_word_index
    line_lst = sorted(list(line_set))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I was wondering, if someone could take a look at my codes and give me hints about fixing this error. Thanks

Comment: On what line does the error occur? That would help to localise your problem. If you found out the line error, you should use that information to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Edited my question to include the complete error report. Hope it helps.

Comment: I see you have some `print` statements in your code. In particular, what is the output of the `print(index_lst)` in your run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you want a *list* of lines for each word, not only the last line you encountered the word. If so, the `word_map` should be a map from words to *lists of line numbers*, not just to single *numbers*. Hence the line for adding a line number for a word is now `word_map[word]+=[line_no]`. The `defaultdict` was used instead of a simple dictionary to avoid writing the `if word not in word_map: word_map[word] = []` part.

Here is a working version:

```
import string, collections
def build_word_index():
    input_file=(input('file name: '))
    input_file_open=open(input_file,'r')

    word_map = collections.defaultdict (list)
    line_no = 0
    w=[]

    for line in input_file_open:

        word_lst = line.strip().split()

        word_lst = [w.lower().strip(string.punctuation) for w in word_lst]

        w.append(word_lst)           

        for word in word_lst:
                word_map[word]+=[line_no]
        line_no+=1

    print(word_map)

    index_lst = sorted(list(word_map.items()))
    print(index_lst)

    for word, line_set in index_lst:
        line_lst = sorted(list(line_set))
        line_str = str( line_lst[0] )
        for line_no in line_lst[1:]:
            line_str += ", {}".format( line_no )
        print("{:14s}:".format(word), line_str )



    input_file_open.close()

build_word_index()
```

Example input:

```
one two
three three four
one two four
four three
```

Example output:

```
file name: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'one': [0, 2], 'three': [1, 1, 3], 'two': [0, 2], 'four': [1, 2, 3]})
[('four', [1, 2, 3]), ('one', [0, 2]), ('three', [1, 1, 3]), ('two', [0, 2])]
four          : 1, 2, 3
one           : 0, 2
three         : 1, 1, 3
two           : 0, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list `index_lst` is the product of a call to a dict's `items` method, which will give you a `list` of `tuple`s containing its keys and values.

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> d.items()
dict_items([('b', 2), ('a', 1)])
```

When you iterate over it the way you are, your first identifier names your current key and the second names the current value of your loop:

```
>>> for a, b in d.items():
...     print("a: {}, b: {}".format(a, b))
... 
a: b, b: 2
a: a, b: 1
>>> # Notice the keys are unsorted!
```

The next line of your loop, you try to pass your second identifier `line_set` to the `list` constructor, which makes a list out of anything that supports iteration.

```
line_lst = sorted(list(line_set))
# Hint: this is referenced in your error message
```

But `line_lst` is not an iterable object! It's just a normal integer (`int`), so Python gives up:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been answered, but here's my take on it.  Haven't tried the code, but I think it should work.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

def build_word_index(filename):
    word_index = defaultdict(list)

    with open(filename,'rb') as word_file:
        for i, line in enumerate(word_file):
            line = line.strip().lower()
            for word in line.split():
                word_index[word].append(i)

    for word in sorted(word_index):
        print word + ': ' + ', '.join(map(str,word_index[word]))

    return dict(word_index)
```

Comment: Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: You may want to watch this video by Raymond Hettinger. http://youtu.be/OSGv2VnC0go